# how to speed up get data on virtual table mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

hy, i have 2 virtual table,
here I have 2 virtual tables ,,

virtual table 1 : contains union 2 table,

virtual table 2 :
contains virtual table 1 and join 1 table.

virtual table 2 is used for computing for various functions.

for now with 2 virtual tables to perform 1 computation function takes more than 350 seconds, and I need under 60 seconds for each function

this is my query sql :

table virtual 1 **v_dvc5** :

```
    SELECT 
dvc0005.NIK, dvc0005.Enroll 
FROM dvc0005 
UNION DISTINCT SELECT dvc0004.NIK, dvc0004.Enroll 
FROM dvc0004
```

table virtual 2 **v_dvc0005** :

```
SELECT
    v_dvc5.NIK,
    v_dvc5.Enroll,
    emp0003.Gender,
    emp0003.Shift_ID
FROM
    v_dvc5, emp0003
WHERE
    Emp0003.IsActive = 'T' 
    AND YEAR(DATE(v_dvc5.Enroll))=YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) 
    AND emp0003.NIK=v_dvc5.NIK
```

Comment: (1) What is a "virtual table"?  (2) Why are you not using `JOIN`?  (3) Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want would help -- and if performance is an issue, so would information on table sizes and indexes.

Comment: Run performance tuning. We can not help you in this since we require more specific details. You need to start the tuning and then ask specific questions. One thing I can say whiteout knowing your database and queries is to remove `UNION DISTINCT` and move to `UNIOT ALL`. The `DISTINCT` is filtering the duplicates, but this is consuming time and resources. If you have duplicates, remove them manually from the tables and start using `UNION ALL`